# How often is a person allowed to delete the questions?

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-overflow

During the last a couple of days I came across the same problem twice.

The same person keeps asking questions and then deleting them.

I'm afraid these links are not visible for everyone, but definitely are available for moderators:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784179/how-can-i-do-this-faster-than-cursor
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826057/how-can-i-do-this-with-model-clause-instead-of-cursor

The first time I spend 30 minutes to write a query which is no longer available for anyone.
The second time, the person asks almost the same question which requires very minor fixes to the original solution. Many people are trying to help, but eventually question is deleted again.

This is quite demotivating.

How often person can do that?

Can I suggest marking such persons so other people would not be wasting time trying to help?

Comment: There's a maximum of 5 posts a day, see [The Complete Rate Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/295232).

Comment: Was going to upvote this as valid thing to discuss then noticed it's actually a feature request.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, I was thinking that if I do not like something I should suggest an improvement. That is all the reasoning.

Comment: Sure, it's legit to request such thing (never said this should be closed or deleted, just that I downvoted), I just oppose the idea. I don't want to mark people or be marked.

Comment: As its a feature request, I suggest you to ask more for a change to the ban trigger, as in your case the OP asked twice on the same SE site the same low quality question. I see it as a way to try to evade downvote/closure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both questions you link are of particularly poor quality, demonstrating poor research effort. They are essentially "give me the code" requests.

Answering a poor question is at the answerer's risk.

The voting system can help prompt an OP to delete a question - they are able to do that unless there are answers with a net positive score. Your answers, sadly, did not achieve a positive score, and so the OP (rightly) deleted the questions.

If a particular user is systematically deleting questions, then eventually rate-limiting and banning mechanisms will kick in automatically.

Comment: Fair enough. Can I request a feature to mark profiles who loves to delete questions? :)

Comment: @DrYWit I recommend not requesting that because features that focus on the poster rather than their content typically attract a lot of downvotes.

Comment: @DrYWit: I don't really see what that would achieve, other than incriminating folk which I can't see being a good thing in any circumstance. Why don't you avoid answering poor questions, or make sure your answer is good enough to attact upvotes?